# current date and time in C++

Tags: c++, date, time

Why does this function return Eastern_Daylight_Time instead of EDT while it shows PST and UTC correctly? example - 2012-09-27@10:07:10(Eastern_Daylight_Time)  and 2013-03-28@07:07:27(PDT)

```
 std::string cur_date_time()
{
  static char buf[256]= {0};
  time_t curtime= time (NULL); //Get the current time
  struct tm *p_loctime=localtime(&curtime);//Convert it to local time representation

  // Format local time in a nice format. 
  strftime(buf, 255, "%Y-%m-%d@%H:%M:%S(%Z)", p_loctime);
  return std::string(buf);
}
```

Can i do something do have one standard format ? like EDT and PDT or Eastern_Daylight_Time and Pacific_Daylight_Time

Comment: This is going to be fairly OS specific. What OS are you on?

Comment: It's dependent on what you have in your timezone configuration files, and how you have the `$TZ` environment variable set.

Comment: Oh yeah, both the values come from different OS but since they are stored in the same database I wanted to have a standard format

Comment: @Barmar echo $TZ -> US/Pacific

Comment: What's TZ on the system in EDT?

Comment: That's Windows and there's no TZ

Comment: It *might* be due to the fact that some timezone abbreviations are not unique. EDT could also refer to the (Australian) Eastern Daylight Time, which is UDT+11. If you want to be portable, you should use the offset, use `%z`.

Comment: Windows does have a timezone, of course; it's just not kept in an environment variable.  I can recommend Boost's Date_Time, but it's not a trivial library; for my app, I ended up needing to create a new locale and imbue the output stream with it in order to get date formatting working the way I wanted.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to set TZ variable manually in Windows ?